# SQL server suddenly backups are slow and async_io_completion shows suspended for long time

Tags: sql-server

50GB database - full backup normally takes 14 (10 minutes backup, 4 minutes to compress).  Suddenly the backup execution time has been climbing upward to 3-4 hours.   Backup dest is a Network path.

To eliminate the network as an issue, used backup to 'NUL:' - same results 4 hrs.

During the full backup async_io_completion is showing "suspended" examples below:
(1161299ms)ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION  1pm / 22% complete
(2838894ms)ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION  2pm / 60% complete
(3969124ms)ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION  230pm / 77% complete
(4818588ms)ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION  245pm / 80% complete
(5816122ms)ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION  3pm / 86% complete
(6695511ms)ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION  315pm / 89% complete

checked VLF count is low (less than 100) /  Tried SQL native backup - same results / DBCC checkdb - no errors.

**HERE IS THE KICKER**....Took a full backup of this 50gb and created a new db on the same SQL instance (alongside orig db).  Executed a full backup on the newly created db and the backup time is back to normal 14 minutes.

Anyone has suggestions on why the newly copy of the same db would perform correctly?  Is there something SQL related that can be checked/verified to determine root cause?  Leaning towards SAN or VM issue, need proof.

**Env info:**
VM environment
Windows 2016 32GB
SQL Standard 2017 CU16

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se. This all seems to point to issues on the disk (saturation for example) itself if you are backing up to `'NUL'`. A newly created database would be empty (even if it takes 50GB of pre allocated space it can still be empty) and would not take as much time as the database that has 50GB of actual data to back up.

Comment: Or are you restoring the same database to then take a backup of the same data? If yes,  are you performing both backups at the same time?

Comment: First... Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I am restoring the same db with the same data to new db.  The new db full backup takes 14 minutes as expected.   No, not executing backups at the same time.  The orig db takes 3-4 hrs for full backup to complete.

Comment: Is the size of the resulting backup file the same for both?

Comment: Good Question Josh - Yes the backup file size is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

Check for log file fragmentation

use slow_database
go

select count(*) from sys.dm_db_log_info ( db_id() )

if this number is high (>10,000s) then maybe the log file fragmentation is the culprit

Comment: Thanks for reply Mo64.  count=159 (matches orig and copy of orig).  Think of anything else to verify\check please submit it.

Comment: could it be you haven't cleaned out the history tables in MSDB ?

Comment: the MSDB history is being cleaned, thanks for the comment I kinda hoped that was the issue/fix.

Comment: **Possibly resolved** - Cleared "full backup" execution plans from cache - higher io and execution elapsed times.  Still testing , so far backup execution times are back to normal.